# Drupal 7 - Add tab link to Node Edit Form

Tags: drupal, menu, edit

Developing a module for Drupal 7 I can't seem to find how to add a link to neither the horizontal or the vertical tab when editing a node.
I'm pretty sure I have to use hook_menu_alter but still...

[menu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYMYd.png)

[menu 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPKGk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `hook_menu_alter`, you can just use `hook_menu` to define the new path:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_global_menu() {
  $items['node/%/some_action'] = array(
    'title' => 'This Is A new Tab',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_some_action_tab',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Replace `some_action` with the actual sub path you want to use, and `mymodule_some_action_tab` with the actual callback function for the tab.